# How to perform automated removal of attributes from a set of a large number of attributes

Tags: machine-learning, weka

So I've got a large dataset of 2304 **numeric** attributes and the class attribute), and I want to perform feature selection to remove misleading and redundant attributes. This is because I will be running discretization to make them nominal and then run Naïves Bayes on the dataset.

However, in the select attributes tab in Weka, it only lists them in ranking order. I know there is a remove filter in the preprocess tab but it only takes in a range or number of the attribute(s).

Is there was an automated way of removing these, because of such a large dataset?

Answer (score 0):

In the Preprocess tab,
Choose the AttributeSelection filter (supervised attribute filter).
Configure evaluator and search as desired.
Apply.

This will only keep the ones that pass the filter (keeping the class attribute, of course). 
If you like the result, save this as a new arff file.

Comment: I chose the `InfoGain` filter and it still keeps all 2304 attributes plus the class but doesnt remove any.